# Best way to fetch 24K records and stuff in sql

Tags: sql, t-sql, query-performance

I have query which fetches addresses of industry xyz. Which has around 24K records. And those has to display in Level1->Level2->Level3->Level4->Level5->Level6 format in one column of excel sheet.

It took more than 30 min to execute.

```
Select Left(REPLACE(STUFF(
            (
            SELECT Char(10) + LevelPath
            FROM #TempIndustryAddress ubu  WITH (NOLOCK)
            WHERE LevelPath<> ''        
            AND industrycode= ubu.industrycode
            GROUP BY LevelPath  
            FOR XML PATH('')            
            )
    ,1,1,''), '&amp;','&'),32766) AS [Industry Addresses]
```

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Netra S W.

Answer (score 0):

Two things.  First, remove the `GROUP BY` from the subquery -- unless you know you have duplicates (which would be string).

Second, add an index on `#TempIndustryAddress(industrycode, LevelPath)`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. In #TempIndustryAddress we are doing insert and delete operation. We tried adding index on it. but it lower the performance of query.